# Org mode: Issue with export using HTML template with #+SETUPFILE

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have download two HTML themes from [this git](https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes/blob/master/README.org) to my home directory. Following the instruction I have put the following line on top of my .org file:

```
#+SETUPFILE: "/home/myusername/org-html-themes/setup/theme-readtheorg-local.setup"
```

where theme.readtheorg-local.setup contains the following:

```
$ cat "/home/myusername/org-html-themes/setup/theme-readtheorg-local.setup"
# -*- mode: org; -*-

#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/readtheorg/css/htmlize.css"/>
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/readtheorg/css/readtheorg.css"/>

#+HTML_HEAD: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
#+HTML_HEAD: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
#+HTML_HEAD: <script type="text/javascript" src="styles/lib/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.min.js"></script>
#+HTML_HEAD: <script type="text/javascript" src="styles/readtheorg/js/readtheorg.js"></script>
```

**However, when I export using 'C-c C-e h o' the template is not applied at all.**

I have tried putting the following on top of my org file before exporting it. This didn't do anything

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/readtheorg/css/htmlize.css"/>
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/readtheorg/css/readtheorg.css"/>

#+HTML_HEAD: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
#+HTML_HEAD: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
#+HTML_HEAD: <script type="text/javascript" src="styles/lib/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.min.js"></script>
#+HTML_HEAD: <script type="text/javascript" src="styles/readtheorg/js/readtheorg.js"></script>
```

My ~./.emacs init file does not contain anything that relates to org-html. The only customized value is quoted below for ease of reference. org-html-preamble is currently set to STANDARD (default value).

```
(customize-set-variables
'(org-html-html5-fancy t))
```

Could someone please advise what I have done incorrectly and is there any extra configuration that is needed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured the solution for this.

If I point the directive #+SETUPFILE to the non-local file which is **theme-readtheorg.setup**, everything worked.

Looking into the content of **theme-readtheorg-local.setup** I figured to get this working I may need to enter in the actual path to the css stylesheets.

For now I'm pretty happy with using the non-online setup file.